# How to remove empty lines while preserving the formatting of the richtextbox in c#

Tags: c#, formatting, richtextbox, removing-whitespace, preserve

I wish to preserve the italics in the text while removing all the empty lines. I can't seem to be able to do it.

I used this code. It removes the empty lines but the text the italics.

```
richTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, @"^\s*$(\n|\r|\r\n)", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Golden Rule about `RichTextBoxes` is to **never** change the `Text` directly, once it has **any** formatting.

To add you use `AppendText` and to change you need to use the `Select, Cut, Copy & Paste..` methods to preserve the formatting!

```
string needle = "\r\r";  // only one possible cause of empty lines

int p1 = richTextBox1.Find(needle);
while (p1 >= 0)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = p1;
    richTextBox1.Select(p1, needle.Length);
    richTextBox1.Cut();
    p1 = richTextBox1.Find(needle);
}
```

For multiple needles you'll need to call the code multiple times, I'm afraid..

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing empty lines from its Rtf Text. The sample code given below will work for you.

```
String[] allLines = richTextBox1
                    .Rtf
                    .Split( new string[] { Environment.NewLine },StringSplitOptions.None);

dynamic linesWithoutEmptyLines = from itm in allLines 
                                 where itm.Trim() != "\\par" 
                                 select itm;

richTextBox1.Rtf = string
                   .Join(Environment.NewLine, linesWithoutEmptyLines);
```

It will preserve the formatting of text and going to remove all the empty lines.

Comment: +1 for including `\\par` -1 for assuming that `Environment.NewLine` is a good idea. It hardly ever is..